# Firebase DataSnapshot Not Filling Object

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object in a firebase database that I am trying to extract from a snapshot.

The JSON object from firebase is:

```
"-KoVHZ8YVll0RiI2GwKb" : {
    "name" : "Name 1",
    "phone_number" : "4443335555"
}
```

I am trying to safe it in an object that looks like this

```
public class Contact {
    private String mName;
    private String mPhoneNumber;

    public Contact() {
        mName = "";
        mPhoneNumber = "";
    }

    public String getName() { return mName; }
    public String getPhoneNumber() { return mPhoneNumber; }
    public void setName(final String name) { mName = name; }
    public void setPhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber) { mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber; }
}
```

I am calling

```
Contact contact = snapshot.getValue(Contact.class);
```

The contact object only has the name populated and not the phone number. The documentation just states that there must be public getters and an empty constructor in order for this to work. My guess is something is wrong with my naming convention anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am aware that I can extract the data out by doing this:

```
mName = (String) snapshot.child("nane").getValue();
mPhoneNumber = (String) snapshot.child("phone_number").getValue();
```

But then what is the point of creating the P.O.J.O.?

Comment: That didn't work. I have tried setting all PhoneNumbers to phone_number and can't get it to work.

Comment: please post the database snapshot

Comment: It is posted, very first

Comment: Please show the actual JSON, not the logcat output. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added the actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Contact.java like this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Contact {

   private String name;
   private String phone_number;

   public Contact() {
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getPhone_number() {
       return phone_number;
   }

   public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
       this.phone_number = phone_number;
   }
```

}

Comment: That works but creates a pretty ridiculous naming scheme. Why does it get `mName` but not `mPhoneNumber`